# AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'number_of_selfloops'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, networkx, graph-theory, pygraphviz

I am trying to run graph drawing code in my pc via jupyter notebook. Networkx ,pygraphviz, and nxpd are installed in my pc.But I found AttributeError after running

**draw(G, layout='circo')**

How can I fix this problem?
Error is in the description below:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d4524714330e> in <module>
----> 1 draw(G, layout='circo')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nxpd/nx_pydot.py in draw_pydot(G, filename, format, prefix, suffix, layout, args, show)
    455 
    456     # Draw the image.
--> 457     G2 = to_pydot(G)
    458     G2.write(fobj, prog=prog, format=ext)
    459     if close:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nxpd/nx_pydot.py in to_pydot(G, raise_exceptions)
    247         graph_type = 'graph'
    248 
--> 249     strict = G.number_of_selfloops() == 0 and not G.is_multigraph()
    250 
    251     # Create the Pydot graph.

AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'number_of_selfloops'
```

The code is given below:

```
import networkx as nx
import pygraphviz as pgv
from nxpd import draw, nxpdParams
nxpdParams['show'] = 'ipynb'
G = nx.DiGraph()


G.add_edge("a", "b")
G.add_edge("b", "c")
G.add_edge("c", "d")
G.add_edge("d", "e")
G.add_edge("e", "c")
G.add_edge("a", "d")
draw(G, layout='circo')
```

Comment: Which version of `networkx` you are using? Because in the current stable release the line states correctly `nx.number_of_selfloops`, see: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pydot.html#to_pydot. As a quick fix you can exchange the line or I would recommend to update `networkx`

Comment: i used networkx of 2.5 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `nxpd` seems like it was last updated years ago. You can modify the line by yourself (see https://github.com/chebee7i/nxpd/blob/master/nxpd/nx_pydot.py#L249) and exchange `G.number_of_selfloops` with `nx.number_of_selfloops(G)`.
However, I guess their are more issues with `nxpd` and I would recommend to simply use `networkx` own interface to `graphviz`, see e.g. [`graphviz_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout.html#networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout):

```
pos = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog="circo")
nx.draw(G, pos)
```